# Setting groovysh classpath from a pom

Tags: java, maven-2, groovy

I have a java project (not using groovy) but I'd like to interactively play with my java classes within groovysh. Is there an easy way to use the pom from my project to set the classpath of groovysh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MOP](http://mop.fusesource.org/index.html) might help:

> #### Scripting Goodies
>
> Other times, you just need need the
>   CLASSPATH so you can use it in a
>   manually crafted script your running.
>   Try this.
>
> ```
> mop classpath org.apache.camel:camel-example-pojo-messaging
> ```

**Update:**  The above command can be used to output the classpath of an existing maven artefact. For example:

```
$ ./mop classpath org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.3.2.GA
```

Prints the following output:

```
/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/pascal/opt/mop/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
```

That can be used somewhere else. As I said, it *might* help but I'm not 100% sure it will suit your needs (it seems the artifact needs to be deployed in a remote repo).

Comment: how would I get it to dump me into groovysh with a pom's dependencies resolved? I clicked on the documentation link on the site and it said "TODO" :/

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record, I've found a way to do it which I consider **much more elegant** when the project uses the [gmaven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN): run [`mvn groovy:shell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gmaven-generated/gmaven-plugin/shell-mojo.html) and you're ready to issue commands with the same classpath available to groovysh as the one available to the project in question!

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to classpath with `-cp` e.g.

```
groovysh -cp some.jar:another.jar
```